# Let $(a_n)$ be a non-increasing sequence of positive real numbers and $\Sigma a_n$ converges. Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n a_n=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

It is true with convergent p-series and geometric series. If it is true, how we establish this? Note the convergence of the series is crucial, for instance consider harmonic series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the series is convergent then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}a_k=0$$
and since $(a_n)$ is non-increasing and positive:
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k\ge \frac12(2na_{2n})\ge0$$
and

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}a_k\ge \frac{n+1}{2n+1}((2n+1)a_{2n+1})\ge0$$
hence by the squeeze theorem we see that 
$$na_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$

Comment: Note that this is more or less the grouping used in the proof of the Cauchy condensation test, which provides a slightly more direct approach (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hint: Consider the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting how to apply Cauchy Condensation Test to establish $lim n a_n =0$.

Comment: @Priya The test tells you that $2^na_{2^n}$ converges, which means these terms go to zero. You can use these to 'sandwich' the other terms to show that $ka_k$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

non-increasing or decreasing?
Since $\sum a_n$ converges, for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $N$ s.t. for any $n>N$, we have$$a_{[\frac{n}{2}]}+a_{[\frac{n}{2}]+1}+\cdots+a_{n}<\epsilon.$$As $a_n$ is non-increasing (decreasing), it follows$$(n+1-[\frac{n}{2}])a_n<\epsilon.$$Now it's easy to see $\lim na_n=0$.